# html section gives unwanted result

Tags: css, html

Hello i'm new to html and css. I wanted to use a section to display some images but it gives me a strange problem. when I use div for my section in html I get the wanted result but when I only use < section > I don't get the same result. Can some one help me to use only section in my html and not the div ? 
this my css code:

```
#content2{
 margin: 30px 0;
 background: white;
 padding: 20px;
 clear: both;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
 text-align: center;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.section {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px;
}

.section a {
 color: orange;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1em;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}

.section p {
 color: black;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1em;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<div id="content2">
    <h4>Onze producten</h4>
    <div class="section">
        <a href="../html/kleding.html#Pika"> Pika deken</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html#Pika"><img src="../images/NB1.jpg" /></a>
        <p>€19.99</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <a href="../html/kleding.html#City">City boy</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html#City"><img src="../images/peuter1.jpg" /></a>
        <p>249.99</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <a href="../html/kleding.html#Classy">Classy girl</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html#Classy"><img src="../images/peuter9.jpg" /></a>
        <p>€244.99</p>
    </div>
     <div class="section">
        <a href="../html/kleding.html#Outdoors">Outdoors</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html#Outdoors"><img src="../images/girl1.jpg" /></a>
        <p>€129.99</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you specify `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the page, to indicate HTML5 is being used (needed mainly for IE)

Second, `<section>` is not a block level element, e.g. a `<div>` is a block level element.

to fix this, add this to your `.section` CSS

`display: block`

this will cause a `<section>` to behave like a `<div>` and should fix your problem.

Comment: Are you sure <section> is not display:block by default? Can you point to some doc that says it's inline. It seems to behave as block in some simple tests.

Comment: the display:block makes everything display vertically, while i want it to be displayed horizontaly.

Comment: this link shows it all: http://www.tutorialchip.com/tutorials/html5-block-level-elements-complete-list/

Comment: PS: If you have `<div>` elements, this should be the same, or something else that you haven't posted here is changing the default behaviour of DIVS only, e.g. `.someparent div {float: left}`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're using `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your HTML document.